# Fetch Items in LINQ where child entities fulfill certain conditions

Tags: c#, linq, list, nhibernate

I'm trying to return a list of **TrackInformationRecord**, done by:

```
return _trackInformationRepository
           .Fetch(t => t.TrackPartId == trackPart.Id && t.IsDeleted == false)
           .ToList();
```

However, the TrackInformationRecord contains a list of SessionInformationRecord in TrackInformationRecord.Sessions and I only want to take Sessions with IsDeleted == false.

I tried the following but it did't work:

```
return _trackInformationRepository
      .Fetch(t => t.TrackPartId == trackPart.Id && t.IsDeleted == false 
         && t.Sessions.Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false))
      .ToList();
```

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to return list of `Sessions` or `TrackInformationRecord`?

Comment: what is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: 'Where' in Linq does not return a bool value, but a collection.  So you can't use it in a bool check like that.  @RohitVats solution is probably what you are looking for.  Basically is it syntactic sugar for 't.Sessions.Where(s => s.IsDeleted == true).Count == 0'

Comment: @RohitVats I want both. Returning a list of TrackInformationRecord includes a list of Sessions. The only problem is that I can't filter the Session list that comes with it. I'm looking for ways to do so without going through a foreach loop and populating each one, but if there's no straightforward way, I guess that'll have to do.

Comment: Also, your use of `Fetch` is surprising.  What is `_trackInformationRepository`'s type?  `Where` is normally the method you use to apply a filter to a query, whereas `Fetch` specifies your fetching strategy, such as "Go ahead and fetch the `Sessions` while you're fetching these `TrackInformationRecords`."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that all Session's object IsDeleted should be false, you want `All`

```
return _trackInformationRepository
      .Fetch(t => t.TrackPartId == trackPart.Id && !t.IsDeleted
                   && t.Sessions.All(s => !s.IsDeleted)).ToList();
```

But in case, you want any Session's object IsDeleted to be false, you need `Any`-

```
return _trackInformationRepository
      .Fetch(t => t.TrackPartId == trackPart.Id && !t.IsDeleted
                   && t.Sessions.Any(s => !s.IsDeleted)).ToList();
```

On a side note, instead of writing `t.IsDeleted == false`, you can write it like `!t.IsDeleted`.

Comment: I want to get All undeleted Tracks even though they may contain deleted Sessions.
Using "All" omits the parent Track from the list. Using "Any" doesn't seem to do anything, the deleted Session still comes out.

Comment: If you want to filter `Sessions` list, you should filter that list in sperate Linq query or foreach loop. `Select` and `Updation` should always be in separate statements.